# ExtJs Grid Panel that contains links returns false

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have an `ExtJs 3.4 Grid Panel`: Inside, the first column is filled with links on each row.

When I click each row I want to open a details panel in the same page so I've implemented a listener (on `cellclick`). But I also have those links on the first column and I want to navigate away when I click those links, but Ext just rewrites my onclick listener (on link) with return false.

Which is the best approach to achieve that? I have to write another listener or maybe would be a good solution to see if the cell contains a link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Ext.EventObject.getTarget` method to determine target in `cellclick` handler.

Eg:

```
cellclick: function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e) {
    var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);        
    if (e.getTarget('a.x-link', this.body)) {
        alert('link');
    } else {
        panel.body.update(record.get('company'));
    }
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/jD7ZE/2/

Answer (score 0):

This may work, Just try this

```
MyGrid.getSelectionModel().on('select', function (rModel, selectedRecord, idx, oBj) {
        $('#History_links').show();
    });
```